# Hygenic macros in C

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

The [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/cpp/swapmacro.html) declares that a generic SWAP macro in C is essentially impossible and not worth the effort. That sounds like a challenge to me.

It cites 2 main difficulties:

1. Finding a suitable type to use as a temporary variable. There are hacks involving char[] arrays and memcopy, but this sort of solution fails on things like `SWAP(my_int, my_float)`. A lot of compilers support `decltype` style operators that make this easy, but they are nonstandard. For now I will admit defeat and just ask the user to supply a suitable type as the third argument.
2. Finding a safe name for a temporary variable. This is something I think I have a solution for. I can use the stringify operator `#` to stringify the input arguments and compare them to prospective temporary variable names to find one that doesn't match.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SWAP(a,b,type)                          \
do {                                            \
    if ((#a[0] != 'a') && (#b[0] != 'a')){      \
        type a_temp = a;                        \
        a = b;                                  \
        b = a_temp;                             \
    }else                                       \
    if ((#a[0] != 'b') && (#b[0] != 'b')){      \
        type b_temp = a;                        \
        a = b;                                  \
        b = b_temp;                             \
    }else                                       \
    if ((#a[0] != 'c') && (#b[0] != 'c')){      \
        type c_temp = a;                        \
        a = b;                                  \
        b = c_temp;                             \
    }                                           \
} while(0)

int main()
{
    int a_temp = 10, b_temp = 20, c_temp = 30;

    printf("a_temp = %d, b_temp = %d, c_temp = %d\n", a_temp, b_temp, c_temp);
    SWAP(a_temp, b_temp, int);
    printf("a_temp = %d, b_temp = %d, c_temp = %d\n", a_temp, b_temp, c_temp);
    SWAP(a_temp, c_temp, int);
    printf("a_temp = %d, b_temp = %d, c_temp = %d\n", a_temp, b_temp, c_temp);
    SWAP(b_temp, c_temp, int);
    printf("a_temp = %d, b_temp = %d, c_temp = %d\n", a_temp, b_temp, c_temp);

    return 0;
}
```

I've seen the issue of accidental capture brought up in many discussions and not seen anyone mention that you could do this, either to recommend or condemn it. Is this a good idea?

Comment: Use `##` to create a new name. `a##b` must be different from both `a` and `b` since it is longer than either. Then you can use it, inside a new scope (braces) as a name for a temporary object.

Comment: What happens if you have `int *a_temp` and `int *b_temp` and you `SWAP(*a_temp, *b_temp, int)`? Or what if you have `#define a_temp *a`?

Comment: Your macro creates three local variables `a_temp`, `b_temp`, and `c_temp`. What is the benefit you want to achieve?

Comment: @EricPostpischil the ## trick is not guaranteed to work because a compiler only has to recognize the first 31 characters of an identifier. If a is longer, a##b can be considered identical to a.

Comment: @Arkku I think you've got me there. If you want to put up a real answer I'm happy to put a tick next to it

Comment: @harper It should only create one temporary variable. It just picks one of three options via a constant expression to find a name that doesn't match

Comment: @JamesHollis So you hope the compiler doesn't generate code for what it finds in the source by a kind of optimization? I doubt that this will work under all circumstances.

Comment: @JamesHollis: Actually, it would be 63, not 31. 31 is a limit the implementation may have for external identifiers (C 2018 5.2.4.1 1). That limit does not apply for identifiers with internal linkage or no linkage. Essentially, it is a limit permitted on the ability of the linker, not the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fail in some cases if the variables are lvalue expressions, e.g., if you have `int *a_temp` and `int *b_temp`, and you `SWAP(*a_temp, *b_temp, int)`. And since the macro is silently using "common" names like `a_temp`, it might break if there is something like `#define a_temp *a`.

And anyway, it is arguably not generic since you have to pass the type: `SWAP(a, b, int)` is not fundamentally different from `SWAPINT(a, b)`. If we accept passing the type, could we also accept passing the name of the temporary variable? Or even a fixed temporary variable name like `_tmpswap0123456789` – after all, we are accepting the far more common name `SWAP` to be now defined as this macro, so worrying about the name of a temporary variable inside it seems secondary.

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm not really concerned about the type issue here. Also, nearly all code is susceptible to breaking if you `#define` away key variables, But you're right, the stringification approach doesn't doesn't quite work.

Comment: @JamesHollis I agree that a non-perfect macro can still be useful. Personally I might consider using type generic macros for the types I need, for example. Meanwhile the C FAQ referenced in the question is technically correct* that a universal, generic macro is not really doable. *The best kind of correct. =)